# Can $.post function overwrite variables in the parent function

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

Last week I've started to play with javascripts so my knowledge is... very limited. Please be patient with me :-)

I'm writing a simple booking system that stores in MySql the dates and user IDs. It checks if given day is already booked (if yes than isTicket.php returns UserId, if it's still free than returns 0).
As it's possible to select a range of days and I wouldn't like to sent multiple warnings I set variable otherEventFound to false if on any of selected days an other user is already booked.

As shown below I've tried to use this variable "out-side" of post-function and there are two possibilities:

1) If my script contains the line >> alert ("otherEventFound...  << it works.

2) If I remove this line, it doesn't.

I'm a little disorientated. Can somebody explain why this additional alert-line is so important, and more generally is it possible to overwrite the variables in parent function from post.success function?

If it's pure luck than it works with alert-line, what is a proper way of doing it in javascript?

```
parent function
...
var otherEventFound = new Boolean();
var do_the_booking = new Boolean();
otherEventFound = false;
do_the_booking = false;
for ( var i = myStart.getDfJ(); i <= myEnd.getDfJ(); i++)
    {
    // conver i to MySQL format yyyy-mm-dd
    var milliseconds = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 *i;
    var j = new Date(milliseconds);
    var strID = j.toYMD();
    // and ask server if there is other event on this day
    $.post("isTicket.php", { theDay: strID }, 
            function(answ){
               if ( parseInt(answ) == 0 ){
                  do_the_booking = true;
               }
               else {
                  if ( !(parseInt(answ) == currentUserId) ){
                     otherEventFound = true;
                  }
               }
            }
        );
    }

    alert ("otherEventFound " + otherEventFound + "   do_the_booking " + do_the_booking);

    if (otherEventFound==true) {
       alert ("There is not yours event booked on this day.");
       do_the_booking=false;
    };
    if (do_the_booking==true){
       var x=window.confirm("Do you want to book on this/these day/s?")
       if (x) {
          // ... do something like $.post("setTicket.php" ...
       }
    }
```

Comment: Using `new Boolean()` is a bad idea, it behaves in unexpected ways, just assign the a Boolean literal `true` or `false` in the `var` declaration.  Using a [`Boolean` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) like that you can't reliably use it in a conditional statement, `if (new Boolean(false)){}` will always evaluate to true because objects are coerced to true. JavaScript does not use strict typing, you don't have to declare what kind of variable value you are going to store before you store it.

Answer (score 3):

When you do a $.post, that kicks off an asynchronous AJAX request which calls back your inline function a while later. Since you don't want a certain piece of code to execute until a fixed number of asynchronous requests have returned, you are going to have to keep track of how many requests have completed.

The only reason it "works" with the alert is because the alert inserts a pause until you answer it by which point the AJAX call is done 
and executes the inline function.

You basically want to modify your code like this:

```
var otherEventFound = false;
var do_the_booking = false;

var completeRequests = 0;
for ( var i = myStart.getDfJ(); i <= myEnd.getDfJ(); i++)
{
    // do something

    // and ask server if there is other event on this day
    $.post("isTicket.php", { theDay: strID }, 
            function(answ){
                completeRequests++;
                if ( parseInt(answ) == 0 ){
                    do_the_booking = true;
                }
                else {
                    if ( !(parseInt(answ) == currentUserId) ){
                        otherEventFound = true;
                    }
                }

                if (completeRequests == myEnd.getDfJ()) {
                    postProcessing();
                }               
            }
    );
}

function postProcessing() {
    alert ("otherEventFound " + otherEventFound + "   do_the_booking " + do_the_booking);

    if (otherEventFound==true) {
       alert ("There is not yours event booked on this day.");
       do_the_booking=false;
    };
    if (do_the_booking==true){
       var x=window.confirm("Do you want to book on this/these day/s?")
       if (x) {
          // ... do something like $.post("setTicket.php" ...
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation. However this solution does not solve the problem with multiple warnings generated in for-loop. If somebody selects f.e. 5 days and 3 of them are already booked,than this code will 3 times start alert "There is not ..." and twice "Do you want to...". Is there a way to overcome this behavior ?

Comment: I moved whole booking into `setTicket.php`. This script also handles multiple days as well as existing tickets from other users. Never the less thanks for your help.